# Can Voice Over on mobile web pages be guided in any way?

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover

As part of an Accessibility project, I organized a desktop web site to have logical groupings of nodes that have `aria-labels` and keyboard navigation that lets users skim through the groups, and enter a group only if the aria-label describing it sounded relevant to them.

Trying to get this to work on Mobile Safari, I see only a swipe gesture that goes through every element of every group and no way to skim from group to group.

To make this more concrete, some pseudocode:

```html
<div aria-label="A row about X">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <a href="/somewhere">there</a>
  <button>Everyone</button>
</div>

<div aria-label="A row about Y">
  <span>Farewell</span>
  <a href="/somewhere">to</a>
  <button>Frodo</button>
</div>
```

On desktop, its easy to enable users to traverse from div to div, and only enter a div if its of interest.  Are there suggestions on achieving this result on mobile safari?

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the front-end nanodegree program on udacity's accessibility section. To make it more usable for accessibility users on safari, one suggestion is to make it so that it's focusable by using tab index. You can also make your own focus styles to the element so that's it's the most usable on all mobile web browsers.